# Is better battery life assured in new android versions with AOT, KSM

Tags: android

We know google has replaced android dalvik virtual machine by android runtime 'ART'. It also introduced ahead of time compilation instaed of JIT for better user experience. This requires a better memory management. So, KSM (Kernel Samepage merging) comes in place. Now KSM gives a better memory management but it requires more cpu cycle. Which of course costs more battery life. Everybody says(google too I guess) new devices with these features are giving better performance with better battery life.

Now my confusion points are.

1. From mobile device point of view AOT, KSM giving better performance that's ok but how its giving better battery life when KSM is causing more battery drain?
2. Is the optimization in battery coming because AOT draining less battery than JIT? I mean does AOT takes less battery?
3. If the optimization in battery life is coming from AOT is it assured always or sometime it is not assured.
4. How can we be sure that battery saving in AOT is more than battery drain in KSM.